# Delegate method to pass data forward

Tags: swift, delegates, uitextview

I am successfully passing data back between two view controllers using a delegate method.

The first view controller is a "Review" screen and the second is an "Edit" screen which mainly contains a UITextView.

When I change the content of the Text View on the edit screen and hit save it successfully passes to the review screen. However when I return to the Edit screen the UITextView is empty.

How can I make sure the edit screen keeps the value that is stored in the delegate?

Thanks for taking the time to have a look.

**Review View Controller**

```
class AddCampaignViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, TitleViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var titleSubtitle: UILabel!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "AddTitleViewController" {

            let addTitleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddTitleViewController

             addTitleViewController.delegate = self

         }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func setCampaignTitle(campaignTitle: String) {

        titleSubtitle.text = campaignTitle

    }

}
```

**Edit View Controller**

```
protocol TitleViewDelegate {

    func setCampaignTitle(campaignTitle: String)

}

class AddTitleViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var delegate : TitleViewDelegate!

    var campaignTitle : String!

    @IBOutlet var titleTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

        let logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "saveTitle:")

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton

    }

    func saveTitle(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            delegate.setCampaignTitle(titleTextView.text!)

            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segue will create a new `EditViewController` every time.  To pass data forward, you will need to assign the data to an `EditViewController` property and then copy that data into `titleTextView.text` in the `viewDidLoad` method.  This is necessary because the `@IBOutlet`s are not set up and are still `nil` when `prepareForSegue` runs.

So:

1. add the property `var textToEdit = ""` to your `EditViewController`.
2. In `prepareForSegue`, set `addTitleViewController.textToEdit = /* the text you want to edit */`
3. In `viewDidLoad` of `EditViewController`, set `titleTextView.text = textToEdit`.

Note: Your `delegate` should be declared `weak` to avoid a retain cycle (which will cause you to leak memory by never freeing `EditViewController`s.  Your `@IBOutlet`s should also be declared `weak`.